# Get RecursionError / KeyError trying to add Periodic Task in Celery beat

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat, kombu

I try to setup some periodic tasks with Celery beat on Django.
I'm using next setup:

```
python3.6
django==1.11.10
celery==4.2.1
kombu==4.2.1
```

My schedule worker runs in Docker container via docker-compose and starts with next command:

```
celery -A proj beat --loglevel=debug -s /src/celerybeat-schedule
```

Without periodic tasks added everything is ok and I get these lines in console:

```
[2018-08-28 17:06:05,261: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2018-08-28 17:06:05,267: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2018-08-28 17:06:05,298: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:

[2018-08-28 17:06:05,298: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2018-08-28 17:06:05,299: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Waking up in 5.00 minutes.
```

But when I try to add periodic task (right after Celery setup):

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender):
    sender.add_periodic_task(10.0, test.s('hello'), name='add every 10')


@app.task()
def test(arg):
    print(arg)
```

I get KeyError with this lines:

```
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,666: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,666: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,666: WARNING/MainProcess] return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,666: WARNING/MainProcess] KeyError
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,666: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2018-08-28 17:11:56,667: WARNING/MainProcess] 'tz'
```

then same errors with `'timezone'` and `'data'`

and then A LOT OF THIS (RecursionError):

```
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,050: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 987, in __getitem__
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,050: WARNING/MainProcess] if key in self.data:
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,051: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,051: WARNING/MainProcess] return self[k]
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,051: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 987, in __getitem__
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,052: WARNING/MainProcess] if key in self.data:
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,052: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,052: WARNING/MainProcess] return self[k]
```

Final strings are:

```
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,115: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,116: WARNING/MainProcess] module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,116: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 98, in import_from_cwd
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,117: WARNING/MainProcess] package=package,
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,117: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 104, in import_from_cwd
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,117: WARNING/MainProcess] return imp(module, package=package)
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,118: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 92, in import_module
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,118: WARNING/MainProcess] return importlib.import_module(module, package=package)
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,118: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,119: WARNING/MainProcess] return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,119: WARNING/MainProcess] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,121: WARNING/MainProcess] File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,122: WARNING/MainProcess] RecursionError
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,123: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2018-08-28 17:11:57,123: WARNING/MainProcess] maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Can't find solution for this about a week so here I am. I'm ready to give you as many settings as can.

Thanks :)

Very big update, sorry, buy maybe it is could be important. Here is what happens between KeyErrors and start of Recursion:

```
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,467: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,468: WARNING/MainProcess] return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,468: WARNING/MainProcess] KeyError
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,468: WARNING/MainProcess] :
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,468: WARNING/MainProcess] 'data'
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,469: WARNING/MainProcess] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,469: WARNING/MainProcess] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,469: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,470: WARNING/MainProcess] sys.exit(main())
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,470: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,470: WARNING/MainProcess] _main()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,470: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,471: WARNING/MainProcess] cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,471: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,473: WARNING/MainProcess] super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,473: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 275, in execute_from_commandline
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,474: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,475: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 488, in handle_argv
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,476: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.execute(command, argv)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,476: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 420, in execute
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,477: WARNING/MainProcess] ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,477: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 279, in run_from_argv
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,477: WARNING/MainProcess] sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,478: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 363, in handle_argv
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,478: WARNING/MainProcess] return self(*args, **options)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,479: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 238, in __call__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,479: WARNING/MainProcess] ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,480: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/beat.py", line 109, in run
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,480: WARNING/MainProcess] return beat().run()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,481: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 81, in run
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,481: WARNING/MainProcess] self.start_scheduler()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,482: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/apps/beat.py", line 109, in start_scheduler
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,482: WARNING/MainProcess] service.start()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,483: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 588, in start
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,483: WARNING/MainProcess] interval = self.scheduler.tick()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,484: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 293, in tick
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,484: WARNING/MainProcess] self.populate_heap()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,484: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 267, in populate_heap
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,485: WARNING/MainProcess] is_due, next_call_delay = entry.is_due()
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,485: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/beat.py", line 132, in is_due
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,485: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.schedule.is_due(self.last_run_at)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,486: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 163, in is_due
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,486: WARNING/MainProcess] last_run_at = self.maybe_make_aware(last_run_at)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,487: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 78, in maybe_make_aware
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,487: WARNING/MainProcess] return maybe_make_aware(dt, self.tz)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,488: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,488: WARNING/MainProcess] value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,488: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/schedules.py", line 90, in tz
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,489: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.app.timezone
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,489: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 44, in __get__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,489: WARNING/MainProcess] value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,490: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 1260, in timezone
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,491: WARNING/MainProcess] if not conf.timezone:
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,491: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 129, in timezone
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,491: WARNING/MainProcess] return self.first('timezone', 'time_zone')
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,492: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 447, in first
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,492: WARNING/MainProcess] return first(None, (self.get(key) for key in keys))
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,493: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 84, in first
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,493: WARNING/MainProcess] None,
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,493: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 82, in <genexpr>
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,494: WARNING/MainProcess] (v for v in evaluate_promises(it) if (
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,494: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 69, in evaluate_promises
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,494: WARNING/MainProcess] for value in it:
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,495: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 447, in <genexpr>
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,495: WARNING/MainProcess] return first(None, (self.get(key) for key in keys))
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,496: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 452, in get
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,496: WARNING/MainProcess] return self[key]
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,497: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 429, in __getitem__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,497: WARNING/MainProcess] return getitem(k)
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,498: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 278, in __getitem__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,498: WARNING/MainProcess] return mapping[_key]
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,499: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/collections/__init__.py", line 987, in __getitem__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,499: WARNING/MainProcess] if key in self.data:
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,500: WARNING/MainProcess] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/collections.py", line 126, in __getattr__
[2018-08-28 17:46:18,500: WARNING/MainProcess] return self[k]
```

I also try to setup tz / timezone for celery_app:

```
app.conf.timezone = pytz.timezone('UTC')
app.conf.tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
app.timezone = pytz.timezone('UTC')
app.tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
```

And I have TZ settings in Django too...

I've also found start of logs, but it's really the last part I have :(

```
[2018-08-28 18:01:56,536: DEBUG/MainProcess] Setting default socket timeout to 30
[2018-08-28 18:01:56,537: INFO/MainProcess] beat: Starting...
[2018-08-28 18:01:56,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] Current schedule:
<ScheduleEntry: add every 10 somewhere_api.celery.test('hello') <freq: 10.00 seconds>
[2018-08-28 18:01:56,558: DEBUG/MainProcess] beat: Ticking with max interval->5.00 minutes
[2018-08-28 18:01:56,572: CRITICAL/MainProcess] beat raised exception <class 'RecursionError'>: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 42, in __get__
    return obj.__dict__[self.__name__]
KeyError: 'tz'
```

Comment: You may have cut off a little bit too much from those entries. I can't see what triggered the `timezone` and `tz` errors, and can't see what the recursion error is doing. Can we see a bit more of those tracebacks? If you have the *starting lines* that would be helpful too.

Comment: The `tz` error is triggered in a [`cached_property` descriptor](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/master/kombu/utils/objects.py#L5-L45), which means we can't see the context at all here. No idea where the actual attribute is being cached *on*. And moreover, that line has an exception handler to catch that specific error to then be handled. So those errors are probably part of a larger traceback (While handling...) and not really part of the actual problem.

Comment: The `tz` attribute is probably [this one on the scheduler class](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c0947b3a7ddcccb3d4c1d813fcbde180408ba228/celery/schedules.py#L89), which uses `app.timezone`, which is [also a cached property](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c0947b3a7ddcccb3d4c1d813fcbde180408ba228/celery/app/base.py#L1253). This uses `self.conf`, so I'd start looking for [`_load_config` lines](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c0947b3a7ddcccb3d4c1d813fcbde180408ba228/celery/app/base.py#L927) and give us the context from there.

Comment: The problem that it's start of traceback that I could see :(I've already found out that it's connected with cached_property, but it doesn't give me information..

Comment: The cached_property lines are red herrings. They are not the real problem. They are *meant* to throw a `KeyError` that is then handled in an `except` block. They are only part of the chain that then leads to the real failure.

Comment: Sorry, that's still not a helpful section. We are up to the part where either `conf.timezone` or `conf.time_zone` fails. I suspect that the `tz` attribute is just the *first* configuration item being loaded, which then triggers something that causes a recursion error *elsewhere*. But we have to follow the traceback down to the part where it starts repeating first.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's the config that is recursing here, so the config is based on a `collections.abc.MutableMapping` (via the [`ChainMap` class](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c0947b3a7ddcccb3d4c1d813fcbde180408ba228/celery/utils/collections.py#L233)), and that is *colliding* with the [`AttributeMixin` class](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/c0947b3a7ddcccb3d4c1d813fcbde180408ba228/celery/utils/collections.py#L115) when the `MutableMapping` implementation tries to access `self.data`, an attribute that doesn't exist so causes `__getitem__('data')` to be called, etc. Not sure why yet.

Comment: This post looks like a very similar issue: [Python Celery worker\_main "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded"](//stackoverflow.com/q/44176190). Try making sure all your packages are upgraded.

Comment: Yep, found this issue, but can't found what I have to update. Moreover I tried to make clear project with same packages and folder structure and beat works there :/

Comment: This is where I'll have to bow out, as I haven't handled celery config in eons now. Something is wrong there (the timezone attribute loading is b0rked, but *why* it is borked is not something I can further trace just with a bit of source code).

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error and the solution is **to be careful**. One of my Django legacy-app suddenly has another Celery instance which was trying to start with another settings and broke everything.

Answer (score 1):

I was just facing something similar but I only use Celery and RabbitMQ, in the end I deleted the celerybeat-schedule.db and rerun the app then it's fine.